# Windows Phone 7.1 doesn't expose the required methods of php soap service after adding the reference service

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-services, windows-phone-7.1, webservice-client

I've been wasting my time but probably, someone can provide me some help about this one.
I'm trying to consume a simple "Hello world" webservice created on php using nusoap. I can **succefully** achieve this if I only use the **.NET** standard edition for **windows forms**. Firstly, I add the service reference and then I am able to use them with no problems at all. All clean. On the other hand, I tryed to do the same thing **on visual studio 2010 for windows phone and I got nothing**. The wizzard identifies the service but when I try to use the "Hello" method I fail because it is not there. Is this some kind of bug? How do I solve this? Is really annoying :S

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

When you are defining a soap service (in the server side) make sure of one thing: **use** field must be **literal**. I don't really don't understand way but it looks like WP7 doesn't like encoded use. Here´s the code sample:

```
$server->register(
                // method name:
                'ProcessSimpleType',         
                // parameter list:
                array('name'=>'xsd:string'), 
                // return value(s):
                array('return'=>'xsd:string'),
                // namespace:
                $namespace,
                // soapaction: (use default)
                false,
                // style: rpc or document
                'rpc',
                // use: encoded or literal
                'literal', //<--------------- BE CAREFULL WITH THIS ONE
                // description: documentation for the method
                'A simple Hello World web method');
```